# What algorithms exist to go from one order of an array to another using specific functions?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, heuristics

I was wondering which algorithms or approaches exists to be able to solve the following problem.

Having two arrays:

```
arr_start = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
arr_finish = [5,3,6,1,4,2]
```

And declaring some specific functions such as this two, where the first one cut the array in the n-th element as if cutting a deck of cards and the second performs a faro shuffle (which is a perfect shuffle):

```
def cut_arr(n,arr):
r=[1]*len(arr)
for i in range(len(arr)):
    if (i+n)<len(arr):
        r[i] = arr[i+n]
    else:
        r[i] = arr[i+n-len(arr)]
return r


def faro_shuffle(arr):
r = []

for (a, b) in zip(arr[0:3], arr[3:]):
    r.append(a)
    r.append(b)
arr = r
return r
```

The goal of the algorithm would be to find how many times and which of the functions declared we have to use to go from arr_start to arr_finish identifying the shortest path.

In this example, the algorithm I'm asking for would tell us to do a faro shuffle and then cut the array in the third element, getting arr_finish starting from arr_start.

```
arr1 = faro_shuffle(arr_start)
cut_arr(3,arr1)

Output: [5,3,6,1,4,2]
```

The goal in the future would be to work with longer arrays, and declare more functions.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest algorithm (and the only one I can think of) is to produce *n*-fold [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)s of the functions with increasing *n*, and applying the resulting sets of functions in turn. Arguments to a function can be handled by replicating it for each possible value. This example program (which can be expanded with additional functions) finds the solution to the given problem:

```
arr_start = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
arr_finish = [5,3,6,1,4,2]

def cut_arr(n,arr):
    r=[1]*len(arr)
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if (i+n)<len(arr):
            r[i] = arr[i+n]
        else:
            r[i] = arr[i+n-len(arr)]
    return r

def faro_shuffle(arr):
    r = []
    for (a, b) in zip(arr[0:3], arr[3:]):
        r.append(a)
        r.append(b)
    arr = r
    return r

# make a list with the available functions
## for a function with an argument n, replicate it for all possible n
## for a function without an extra n, specify argument None
functions = [(cut_arr, i) for i in range(len(arr_start))] \
          + [(faro_shuffle, None)]

import itertools

for r in itertools.count(0):
    for c in itertools.product(functions, repeat=r):
        print("TRYING", c)
        arr = arr_start
        for f in c:
            func, argn = f
            arr = func(arr) if argn is None else func(argn, arr)
        if arr == arr_finish:
            print("SUCCESS")
            quit()
```

Comment: Thank you Armali for responding. Do you think there is any way of reduce this problem's complexity? Because it seems that the only solution is brute force and if we intend to work with bigger arrays it could take years. Maybe some heuristic algorithm?

Comment: Maybe, or maybe with some artificial intelligence that could find expedient function combinations; but I don't know how.